# PHP - Recursive function to find parents of any given parent - issue

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I hope somebody can help, this is driving me crazy!

I have a simply recursive PHP function for getting all parents to any given parent for a list of categories. You simply pass it the parent category ID for any given category and it will recursively get all the parents further up the tree.

```
function getParentCategoriesById($parent_category_id,array $parents = []){

if(empty($parent_category_id)) {
    return [];
}

$parents[] = $parent_category_id;

$parent_category = DB::builder()->table('product_categories')->find($parent_category_id);

if(!empty($parent_category->parent)) {
    getParentCategoriesById($parent_category->parent,$parents);
}

return $parents;}
```

Let's say category id=100 has 2 parents (33->37), if I dump the $parents array just before the return, the results are:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 33
    [1] => 37
)
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 33
)
```

The first array returned is the correct result, but I don't understand how the function is re-running and then instead returning only the first parent.

Comment: You are not doing anything with the result of your second `getParentCategoriesById` call. And the array itself is not modified, you’d have to pass it per reference for that to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass reference to `$parents` in internal call to `getParentCategoriesById()`

```
function getParentCategoriesById($parent_category_id, array &$parents = []) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, although due to my PHP version I had to pay the reference in the function definition:

private function getParentCategoriesById($parent_category_id,array &$parents = [])

Comment: Also no need to return this array.